# TypeScript: Define a callable type without CallableFunction properties

Tags: typescript, types

Let's declare a type `T` that has a call signature:

```js
type T = () => number;
```

Let's also declare a variable `t` of this type:

```js
declare const t: T;
```

In the TypeScript Playground or an IDE, we immediately see that `t`, being of type `T`, has a great deal of methods and properties that we never declared explicitly: `apply`, `bind`, `caller`, and so on.

How do we declare `T` so that it's defined only by its call signature? (TS 3.8.3+)

Notably, the type `Omit<T, "apply" | "bind" | "caller">` is `{}`, and so is `Omit<T, "">`. Furthermore, `Omit<CallableFunction, "">` is not a callable type according to `tsc`.

Answer (score 2):

For core types (string, number and yes Function), you cannot do it from type declarations.

## Creating your own environment

Compile with `--noLib` and include your own definitions in your `someFile.d.ts` for `interface String`, `interface Function` etc.

The definitions will still apply globally to all `string` / `number` / `Function` etc. For example if you don't include `.bind` it will not be present for *any* functions.

Comment: Great! If I bundle up this solution in a published package, how do I inform consumers that they also need to rewrite the standard library from scratch themselves?

Comment: You add the library as a part of your package and tell the users to compile with `--noLib`